# Use BLE instead of RFID for race timing system

Tags: bluetooth, rfid, bluetooth-low-energy

I've never studied electrical engineering, although lately I'm been increasingly curious about race timing systems. According to the research done so far, usually they use RFID systems to monitor when the athletes cross certain points in the circuit. I'm been wondering if it would be possible to create a similar system by using the increasingly popular BLE technology. As far as I know, BLE beacons emit a signal every x ms, so right from this point I know the readings would not be very accurate when lots of athletes crossed the line at the same time. Anyway, for the points where the order of the athletes is not relevant, would it be a viable option? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Viable yes, but likely more expensive. BLE also needs a battery. Unless there is a problem that RFID doesn't solve, I wouldn't go with BLE.

Answer (score 1):

RF solutions like placing a transmitter on a person seems like it would always be problematic due to the fact that the emitted field can be detected by a receiver from a distance. Without a complex setup to isolate or silo the receiver you would never be really sure from what distance the RF transmissions were detected. I think I would stay away from this type of solution for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to think or compare to is not RFID systems, but active timing transponders which work much like any BLE beacon. The active transponders just aren’t transmitting most of the time. What you need is a way to trigger the beacon when crossing a finish line, then capturing the time and finally sending the data to a receiver, that should then be able to calculate the accurate time of activation of the beacon compared to the time of the receiver.

I think it could be done with BLE Beacons.. You just need a reliable (and kind of accurate) way of triggering them. Active transponder timing today just uses a loop that triggers the the timing chip to send “it’s time” on a 2,4Ghz frequency to the receiver. The receiver then works out the deltas and gives out a time with an accuracy of 1-100ms depending on the transponder used.